# How can I implement such a button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/50386/screenshots/294883/dribbble.jpg

Large red button and Edit button

I tried to create this beautiful button with Elevated Button, but it does not work.

How would you make it?

```
child: PushableButton(
                height: 60,
                elevation: 8,
                hslColor: HSLColor.fromAHSL(1.0, 347, 0.81, 0.55),
                shadow: BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0, 2),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'VS PLAYER',
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    '/match',
                    arguments: {
                      'mode': Mode.PVP,
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this one [A 3D pushable button built in Flutter](https://flutterawesome.com/a-3d-pushable-button-built-in-flutter/)

```
child: PushableButton(
                height: 60,
                elevation: 8,
                hslColor: HSLColor.fromAHSL(1.0, 347, 0.81, 0.55),
                shadow: BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0, 2),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'VS PLAYER',
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    '/match',
                    arguments: {
                      'mode': Mode.PVP,
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment . I did it . but not same

Comment: you have to customize this button style according to your requirement

Comment: Do you want me to share the exact button code?

Comment: I did write code

Comment: https://github.com/bizz84/pushable_button/tree/main/lib